# Waterline query of arrays separated "OR"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to get a sails backend REST call that retrieves me items where either the "country" column or the "subCountry" column matches an array I have. I've tried:

```
{
    skip: 0,
    where: {
        or: [
            {country: ['Argentina', 'Brasil']},
            {subCountry: ['Argentina', 'Brasil']}
        ]
    }
}
```

but it return 0 records.

Looks like the problem is that I have an implicit "in" on each "or" term.
I'm querying to a mongo database.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the answer here? It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a "pretty" idea, but since [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) is basically an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) with a shorter notation form you still should be able to do the long notation form which is the same:

```js
{
    "where": {
        "or": [
            { "country": "Argentina" },
            { "country": "Brasil" },
            { "subCountry": "Argentina" },
            { "subCountry": "Brasil" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Alternately you can just accept using the "native" query form instead:

```js
Model.native(function(err,collection) {
    collection.find({
        "$or": [
            { "country": { "$in": [ "Argentina", "Brasil" ] } },
            { "subCountry": { "$in": [ "Argentina", "Brasil" ] } },
        ]
    }).toArray(function(err,docs) {

    });
});
```

Since there is nothing wrong with that query form itself, just how it is being serialized for MongoDB by waterline.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to accept the answer, I've tweaked my js code to do the OR expansion and it worked ok! :) Thanks!